# unzip a directory in unix

Tags: linux, zip

I tried to `unzip` a folder in Unix:

```
$ unzip sample.zip
```

This is creating the root structure `a/b/c/d/e/f/sample`.

I need to `unzip` a folder in the current directory.

Comment: Can you please try and explain this question a bit more? As it stands it's very unclear what you're asking. There are 3 ways to interpret what you're saying. (1) unzip with no directories (2) blindly unzip just the contents of the folder without knowing it ahead of time, or (3) unzip a specific folder in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

From the `unzip(1)` man page:

```
   -j     junk paths.  The archive's directory structure is not recreated;
          all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default,
          the current one).
```

Comment: Note that this will unpack *all* the files into the current directory, regardless of the in-file directory structure. That is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: If this isn't what the OP wants, the OP should explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: @GregHewgill I *think* I know what the OP is after, and am working on an answer...

Answer (score 1):

#### Unzipping a folder without it's full hierarchy

If you're just trying to unzip the contents of a directory within the zip file without retaining any of the hierarchy this folder is inside of, in the zip file 
then you're out of luck. There is no method that provides this. The problem is with how zip files are created. They are typically built as a solid blob and so are not easily accessible in the way that most would think.

The only 2 approaches I've seen which can do this are to create a loop which goes through the index of a zip file, something like this:

#### Method #1

```
for i in $(unzip -l zipfile.zip); do

   # look for specific location
   # when there, make directory structure you want
   # unzip zipfile.zip $i -d /some/tmp/dir
   # move file from /some/tmp/dir to new directory

done
```

The above can be done in a number of programming languages such as Perl, Python, etc.

#### Method #2

The other method involves making a copy of the zip file and then using the tool `zipnote` to manipulate the index of the files inside the archive, and then extract the files once the zip file's index has been manipulated.

#### Unzipping a folder with it's full hierarchy

If on the other hand you're simply trying to extract a single folder from the zip file, you can use this command to do so:

```
$ unzip "/path/to/archive.zip" "in/archive/folder*" -d "/path/to/unzip/to"
```

#### Example

Sample directory structure.

```
$ tree 
.
|-- 1
|   |-- 2
|   |   |-- 3
|   |   |   `-- 4
|   |   |       `-- 5
|   |   |           |-- file1
|   |   |           |-- file2
|   |   |           |-- file3
|   |   |           |-- file4
|   |   |           `-- file5
|   |   `-- afile
|   `-- afile
`-- afile
```

Zipped up.

```
$ zip -r ../afile.zip .
  adding: afile (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/afile (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/afile (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/ (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/ (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/ (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/file1 (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/file2 (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/file3 (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/file5 (stored 0%)
  adding: 1/2/3/4/5/file4 (stored 0%)
```

Confirming contents of zip file.

```
$ unzip -l ../afile.zip 
Archive:  ../afile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  11-07-2013 16:43   afile
        0  11-07-2013 16:43   1/
        0  11-07-2013 16:43   1/afile
        0  11-07-2013 16:43   1/2/
        0  11-07-2013 16:43   1/2/afile
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/file1
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/file2
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/file3
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/file5
        0  11-07-2013 15:51   1/2/3/4/5/file4
---------                     -------
        0                     13 files
```

Now we unzip just folder 5.

```
$ unzip afile.zip "1/2/3/4/5*" -d new/
Archive:  afile.zip
   creating: new/1/2/3/4/5/
 extracting: new/1/2/3/4/5/file1     
 extracting: new/1/2/3/4/5/file2     
 extracting: new/1/2/3/4/5/file3     
 extracting: new/1/2/3/4/5/file5     
 extracting: new/1/2/3/4/5/file4
```

Confirmation of unzip:

```
$ tree .
.
`-- 1
    `-- 2
        `-- 3
            `-- 4
                `-- 5
                    |-- file1
                    |-- file2
                    |-- file3
                    |-- file4
                    `-- file5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it directly, although it can be done in a slightly roundabout way by unpacking the archive in a temporary location and moving the files into the current directory.

The *problem* is that you don't really know about the structure of the zip file contents, so this is quite hard to solve *in the general case*. If what you want to do is to just "junk" the first directory component and dropping everything under it into the current directory, then we can write a shell script or shell function to do it. I'm going to show you an example for GNU bash; it shouldn't be hard to adapt to other shells if you prefer something else. You can put this at the end of your ~/.bashrc to try it out.

```
unzip_to_current_dir() {
  zipfilenames="$@"
  for zipfilename in ${zipfilenames}; do
    tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
    unzip -d "${tempdir}" "${zipfilename}"
    mv "${tempdir}/*/*" ./
    rm -rf "${tempdir}"
  done
}
```

The idea is to take the zip file names and then, one by one, create a temporary directory, unzip into that directory, move everything in the first level subdirectory of the unzip target directory into the current directory, and then clean up the temporary directory before moving on to the next file. **This effectively removes the first component of the path in the zip file, so that unpacking a zip file that has a/abc, a/bcd, a/cde and a/def/ghi stores those files as ./abc, ./bcd, ./cde and ./def/ghi.**

To easily test if this does what you want, take the four most-indented lines and execute them manually, one at a time, only substituting your own value for `${zipfilename}`. I strongly suggest doing that in a directory that does not hold any critical data; I highly doubt that there is a data-corrupting bug in that script, but: if it breaks, you get to keep all the pieces.